Word VBA insert multiple images and captions at bookmarked location in template document from Access
I have a word template that I am populating from an Access database recordset using VBA. I have bookmarked all of the relevant locations in the template and loop through the recordset using the .SaveAs command to create a new word doc with the data for each record; then repopulate the template for the next record. This is working fine for text.
My challenge now is to add images and a text description (variable number of images) to the word template at a bookmarked location. I have a second recordset queried from within the first recordset loop that has the full file path to the image location and the description of the image(s) for that record. I would like to add the description below the image.
For the text I am using the following from adapted from wordmvp.com
Private Sub btn_ExportWord_Click()

    Dim wApp As Word.Application
    Dim wDoc As Word.Document
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim BMRange As Range
    Dim filepath2 as String
    Dim strQuery as String

    'There is more included above here to define the file path and query but those are working just fine
    Set wApp = New Word.Application
    Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open(filepath2)

    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery)

    If Not rs.EOF Then rs.MoveFirst
    
    Do Until rs.EOF

    'There are 44 bookmarks so only subset included here
    Set BMRange = wDoc.Bookmarks("OtherNotesComments").Range
    BMRange.Text = Nz(rs!OtherNotesComments, "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks.Add "OtherNotesComments", BMRange
    Set BMRange = Nothing
    Set BMRange = wDoc.Bookmarks("OtherNotesComments").Range
    BMRange.Text = Nz(rs!OtherNotesComments, "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks.Add "OtherNotesComments", BMRange
    Set BMRange = Nothing

    wDoc.SaveAs2 filepath & "\" & ReportType2 & rs!PFM_Number & ".docx"

    rs.MoveNext

    Loop

End Sub

I have used the following to insert all of the images successfully added before the .SaveAs; adding the required dimension of the new variables.
If Not rs2.EOF Then rs2.MoveFirst

Do Until rs2.EOF

Set BMImage = wDoc.Bookmarks("PFM_Images").Range
BMImage.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=rs2!FullPath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
wDoc.Bookmarks.Add "PFM_Images", BMImage
Set BMImage = Nothing


rs2.MoveNext

wDoc.SaveAs2 filepath & "\" & ReportType2 & rs!PFM_Number & ".docx"

rs.MoveNext

Loop

What I cannot seem to figure out is how to add the description to the image. I have tried to use the InsertCaption method but get an error when attempting to use that with BMIMage range. Any help would be appreciated.

This is what ended up working in the end; actually two solutions. The first places the image description as plain text below the image, and the second uses the insertcaption method. The insertcaption method is producing some odd page break issues that have yet to be resolved but does work to include the description as a caption.
First solution uses the bookmarks("name").select to place the selection at the bookmark, in this case a placeholder bookmark.  Then uses the with word_application.selection method to insert the image, a carriage return, the description, another carriage return, and then collapses to the end, moves to the next record and loops.
    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery2)

    
    If Not rs2.EOF Then
    
        If Not rs2.EOF Then rs2.MoveFirst
    
        wDoc.Bookmarks("PFM_IMages").Select
    
            Do Until rs2.EOF
        
                With wApp.Selection
                    .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=rs2!FullPath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                    .InsertParagraphAfter
                    .InsertAfter Nz(rs2!Caption, "")
                    .InsertParagraphAfter
                    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                End With
            
                rs2.MoveNext

            Loop
    
    End If
    
    wDoc.SaveAs2 filepath & "\" & ReportType2 & rs!PFM_Number & ".docx"
    
    rs.MoveNext

The second solution involves two loops, the first is as above but omitting the placement of the description text. Then moves back to the first record in the recordset dimensions an integer variable and an InlineShape variable and progresses through the recordset again from i = 1 to the end of the recordset.
    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strQuery2)

    
    If Not rs2.EOF Then
    
        If Not rs2.EOF Then rs2.MoveFirst
    
        wDoc.Bookmarks("PFM_IMages").Select
    
            Do Until rs2.EOF
        
                With wApp.Selection
                    .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=rs2!FullPath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                    .InsertParagraphAfter
                    .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
                End With
            
                rs2.MoveNext

            Loop
            
            rs2.MoveFirst

            i = 1

            Do Until rs2.EOF

                Set ImageIsh = wDoc.InlineShapes(i)

                ImageIsh.Range.InsertCaption Label:=-1, Title:=rs2!Caption, Position:=1, ExcludeLabel:=False

                i = i + 1

                rs2.MoveNext

            Loop
    
    End If
    
    wDoc.SaveAs2 filepath & "\" & ReportType2 & rs!PFM_Number & ".docx"
    
    rs.MoveNext



Here comes a Word VBA snippet to show how to insert image and caption

Option Explicit
Sub InsertImageAndCaption()
    Dim bookmarkName As String
    Dim imagePath As String
    Dim captionText As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim img As InlineShape
    ' modify as needed
    bookmarkName = "PFM_Images"
    imagePath = "d:\temp\2.png"
    captionText = "MyFirstImage"
    ' ***
    ' Check if the bookmark exists
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists(bookmarkName) Then
        ' Set the range to the bookmark
        Set rng = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range
        ' Insert the picture at the bookmark location
        rng.Text = ""
        Set img = rng.InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=imagePath, LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True)
        ' recreate bookmark
        With ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
            .Add Range:=img.Range, Name:=bookmarkName
            .ShowHidden = False
        End With
        ' Insert a caption after the picture
        img.Range.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", Title:=vbTab & captionText, Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
    Else
        MsgBox "Bookmark '" & bookmarkName & "' not found in the document.", vbCritical
    End If
End Sub



Thank you taller, I appreciate the nuance of now of setting the range variable to the bookmark range and then susing that to set the InlineShape variable. It appears that the above removes the image bookmark so it is unclear to me how I would then loop through the images as the bookmark is now no longer available on the subsequent passes through the loop. Any advice you can give is appreciated. Thanks

It appears that the above removes the image bookmark - You can keep the bookmark ( actually it is re-created ) if you think it is useful for the next step processing.  Or using For Each Shp in ActiveDocument.InlineShapes to loop through images.

Great, thanks, can you please elaborate on how re-create the bookmark after the inserted image and caption?

I've updated the code.

So close, as I loop through the image recordset all of the captions are added but only the last image is included. It appears that for the first loop it is adding he image and caption, but for each subsequent loop it is replacing the image and then adding the caption. Any thoughts? Thank you again for your help.

It seems your script places images at the same bookmark location. As I mentioned in my previous comment, the bookmark is recreated with each image insertion. Consequently, the next image replaces the previous one at the same spot, causing the first image to disappear. This is why you only see the last image. You might need to consider a different method for organizing images in the document.
